# Doctrine ManyToMany always returns an empty collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have these two classes with ManyToMany association:

One class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="tripEvents")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="event_trip_registrators")
 */
private $tripRegistrators;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->tripRegistrators = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getTripRegistrators()
{
    return $this->tripRegistrators;
}

public function setTripRegistrators($tripRegistrators)
{
    $this->tripRegistrators = $tripRegistrators;
}

public function addTripRegistrator(User $tripRegistrator)
{
    $this->tripRegistrators->add($tripRegistrator);
}

public function removeTripRegistrator($tripRegistrator)
{
    $this->tripRegistrators->removeElement($tripRegistrator);
}
```

Second class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\Event", mappedBy="tripRegistrators")
 */
protected $tripEvents;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->tripEvents = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getTripEvents()
{
    return $this->tripEvents;
}

public function setTripEvents($tripEvents)
{
    $this->tripEvents = $tripEvents;
}
```

If I call `$event->getTripRegistrators()` (first class), I only get an empty persistent collection.
Do you have any hint why this happens?
If I save items via SonataAdmin, everything works fine, the database table has correct data.

Comment: What query do you use to retrieve data? Have you verified using plain SQL that the query returns the expected result? Have you checked the profiler toolbar for the query being generated/data returned?

Comment: I'm using simple calling of method ``getTripRegistrators()`` without any query. This is not enough?

Comment: It should be enough. Have you check in the `event_trip_registrators` table, is there data with the event you are running the function on?

Comment: How do you get the $event? Can you add the code in your controller?